# Validation rule error triggers page to switch from Lightning to Classic

Tags: lightning, validation-rule

I've created validation rules to dissallow users to change a 'status' field until certain fields are populated. This issue occurs when a user tries to change the 'status' without populating necessary fields, the record produces the error but reloads the page as a Classic page and not a Lightning page.

Any ideas how I can keep the error showing on a Lightning page and stopping it from reverting to classic?